# Показать лидера продаж среди товаров по каждому дню

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно вычислить лидера продаж среди товаров по каждому дню из следующих таблиц.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял задание, нужно получить таблицу с с лидерами на каждый день. Я использую обобщенное табличное выражение для суммирования конкретного товара, проданного за день.

```
WITH sum_quantity_by_days (id_tovar, sales_date, sum_quantity) AS (
SELECT [s].id_tovar, [s].sales_date,  SUM(quantity_kg) AS quantity_kg
FROM [sales] AS [s]
GROUP BY [s].sales_date, [s].id_tovar)
```

В итоге я имею табличку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую SQL Server Management Studio 18.7.

Далее я попробовал найти через группировку:

```
WITH sum_quantity_by_days (id_tovar, sales_date, sum_quantity) AS (
SELECT [s].id_tovar, [s].sales_date,  SUM(quantity_kg) AS quantity_kg
FROM [sales] AS [s]
GROUP BY [s].sales_date, [s].id_tovar)SELECT [s_q_b_d].sales_date, MAX(sum_quantity) AS max_quantity
FROM [sum_quantity_by_days] AS [s_q_b_d]
GROUP BY [s_q_b_d].sales_date
```

Выводит то что нужно, но не полностью (отсутствуют названия продуктов):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну видимо потому что в селекте у тебя два поля, которые и вывелись

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: Вам нужно улучшить то, как вы задаете вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо. Я это учту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее решение.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tovar TABLE (id_tovar INT PRIMARY KEY, tovar_name NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tovar (id_tovar, tovar_name) VALUES
(1, N'сахар'),
(2, N'мука'),
(3, N'гречневая крупа');

DECLARE @sales TABLE (id_sales INT PRIMARY KEY, id_tovar INT, sales_date DATE, quantity_kg INT);
INSERT INTO @sales (id_sales,id_tovar, sales_date, quantity_kg) VALUES
(1, 1, '2011-01-01', 10),
(2, 2, '2011-01-02', 3),
(3, 1, '2011-01-02', 5),
(4, 3, '2011-01-02', 20),
(5, 1, '2011-01-03', 10),
(6, 2, '2011-01-02', 18);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id_tovar, sales_date, SUM(quantity_kg) AS quantity_kg
    FROM @sales
    GROUP BY id_tovar, sales_date
), rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sales_date ORDER BY quantity_kg DESC) AS seq
    FROM cte
)
SELECT rs.sales_date, t.tovar_name, rs.quantity_kg 
FROM rs INNER JOIN 
    @tovar AS t ON t.id_tovar = rs.id_tovar
WHERE rs.seq = 1;
```

**Результат**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| sales_date | tovar_name | quantity_kg |
+------------+------------+-------------+
| 2011-01-01 | сахар      |          10 |
| 2011-01-02 | мука       |          21 |
| 2011-01-03 | сахар      |          10 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подойдёт: `WITH sum_quantity_by_days (tovar_name, sales_date, sum_quantity) AS (
 SELECT [t].tovar_name, [s].sales_date, SUM(quantity_kg) AS quantity_kg
 FROM [sales] AS [s]
  INNER JOIN [tovar] AS [t] ON [s].id_tovar = [t].id_tovar
 GROUP BY [s].sales_date, [s].id_tovar, [t].tovar_name
)
SELECT tovar_name, sales_date, sum_quantity
 FROM sum_quantity_by_days
 WHERE sum_quantity = (SELECT MAX(sum_quantity) FROM sum_quantity_by_days s WHERE s.sales_date = sum_quantity_by_days.sales_date)
GO` Извиняюсь за текст, ещё не понял как в комментариях аккуратно писать код.

Comment: Я не понимаю вашего комментария. У вас была возможность попробовать мой ответ?

Comment: Да, попробовал. То что нужно, спасибо!